# Laravel - how to change root path from / to /quote

Tags: php, laravel

Hello Laravel Experts,

(I am newbie to laravel)

for my Laravel application, I want to change my path from

```
/ to /quote,
```

i.e. the current url -

```
https://example.com/  --> https://example.com/quote/
```

I have changed it at proxy level, but then the images, css, js and livewire all fail.

Then changed the code for images, js and css as below -

```
- read as /images/abc.png => /quote/images/abc.png -
```

and the images folder moved from -

```
 public/images  => public/quote/images
```

and same for js and css
etc.

However, this doesn't work with livewire (livewire.js, or /livewire/update)

In other words, is there a way to change the root URL from / to /quote - without having to meddle with code? may be add a new route - at core level?

Pls advice / code lines

same as described above

Comment: Why not just set up the routes you want to work?  Anything else will 404.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression constraints might be what you're looking for.
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

It would look something like the code below.

```
Route::get('/{any}', function (string $any) {
    redirect('/quote' . $any, 302);
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Comment: Won't this cause an infinite redirect loop?

Comment: Firstly @Olivier - I did not observe an infinite loop.  Secondly, still missing something. Let me explain the setup first. this might have worked, if I was exposing the / as the only application in my nginx, which seems to be causing the issue.  My nginx (i.e proxy) layer is configured as - if there is a call into / - then route it to wordpress codebase.

Comment: Contd...  If there is a call into /quote - then route into laravel codebase. if there is a all into /xyz then route into another app ... etc.  In this setup, Nginx will only forward the calls with URL /quote to laravel codebase, i.e my inbound URL is /quote. So, the /{any} -- here would be /quote/home -- which would be /quote/quote/home - internally ? what should my Route::get be in routes/web.php?

Comment: I changed path in .env for APP_URL - to https://example.com/quote 

and the route now looks like - 
Route::get('/quote/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home'); 

The images / css and js are still under "public/quote" and the respective paths updated. 

The pages come up now, however I get the error - get-quote:233 
        
        
       GET https://example.com/livewire/livewire.js?id=178de384 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: If I use livewire.js manually - as - 
`$ cp ./vendor/livewire/livewire/dist/livewire.js ./public/quote/js/`

Comment: and update - `config/livewire.php` with value `'asset_url' => '/quote/js/livewire.js',`, then this error goes off with GET livewire.js

Comment: However, further in page, a new error comes up - ` POST https://uatx1.podx.io/livewire/update 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: In summary, I was trying to manually update the path of livewire.js - and not allow it to interpret by default, however, this doesnt seem to be working as well. Not sure if the /quote/livewire/update would work ... as this path is not registered with app anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to change the URL for assets (css, js, images, etc)? If not then you could just add prefix and group to your route.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('index);
});

Route::prefix('quote')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
        // Authenticated routes
    });

    Route::get('/', [IndexController::class, 'index'])->name('index'); // top/LP

    // Not Authenticated routes
});
```

URL will be: `https://example.com/  --> https://example.com/quote/`

Everytime users access `https://example.com/` they will be redirected to `https://example.com/quote/`

**ADD**

If you want to move your assets to `/quote` then move all assets to `public/qoute` folder. Though you will need to update how you use your assets like the following:

1. `{{ asset('js/app.js') }}` to `{{ asset('quote/js/app.js') }}`
2. `{{ URL::asset('js/app.js') }}` to `{{ URL::asset('quote/js/app.js') }}`

Comment: Tried the first set of Routes with prefix, it didnt work.

Comment: What do you mean it did not work? Did you check your routes with `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: clear cache with `php artisan optimize:clear`